# setting object prototype (in example)

Tags: javascript

I`m trying to understand example from *"java script - understanding weird parts" course*. It is explained, that when the `Greeter.init.prototype` is set to `Greeter.prototype` it is done for cleaner code purpose, so we can set the methods in `Greeter.prototype`. But when try the code without that setting -  to store my methods directly in `Greeter.init.prototype` i got an error in the console:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'prototype' of undefined

Why is that?

- The example working part:

> (function(global,$){
>
> ```
> var Greeter = function (firstName){
>     return new Greeter.init (firstName); 
> }
>
> Greeter.prototype = {};
>
> Greeter.init = function (firstName){
>
>     var self = this;
>     self.firstName = firstName
> }
>
> Greeter.init.prototype = Greeter.prototype;
> ```
>
> })(window, jQuery);

- changed part with error (line7&15):

> (function(global,$){
>
> ```
> var Greeter = function (firstName){
>     return new Greeter.init (firstName); 
> }
>
> Greeter.init.prototype = {};
>
> Greeter.init = function (firstName){
>
>     var self = this;
>     self.firstName = firstName
> }
> ```
>
> })(window, jQuery);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the prototype of a property (`init`) you haven't initialised yet.

```js
var Greeter = function (firstName){
    // also don't put spaces before parentheses of function calls
    return new Greeter.init(firstName); 
}

// Greeter.init is undefined here - so it throws
Greeter.init.prototype = {};

Greeter.init = function (firstName){

    var self = this;
    self.firstName = firstName
}
```

You should first initialise init and the set the prototype

```js
var Greeter = function (firstName) {
    // also don't put spaces before parentheses of function calls
    return new Greeter.init(firstName); 
}

Greeter.init = function (firstName) {
    var self = this;
    self.firstName = firstName
}

// Greeter.init is no longer undefined
Greeter.init.prototype = {};
```